# How to load interop.excel.dll with Loadfrom

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, loading, gettype

How to use the Assembly.Gettype?

I have read the microsoft references and do not know, why myExcelType is allways NULL. The dll should be loaded, because myAssembly.GetName() is working fine.

```
        Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll");

        Type myExcelType = myAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass");

        object myExcelObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myExcelType);
```

Comment: I think your looking for `dynamic myExcelObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myExcelType);` ?

Comment: There is no simple explanation for that.  There just isn't any point in using the PIA that way, you'll much favor dynamic myExcelObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"));